# ParseError syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php, syntax, yii2, syntax-error

I am pretty new to php and yii2. I think the error is about line 19 and/or about line 30, but I am not sure and I don't know why I have it. I will appreciate any help.

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = Yii::$app->name;
?>


    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>

        <p class="lead">Hello, it's me, your online library</p>

    </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h1>New Books</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ($books as $b) {?>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              <img src="..." alt="...">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
                <p>...</p>
                <p style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <?php}?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 well">
        Right Menu
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's minor syntax error. There should be space in `<?php` and closing brackets `}`. Like shown below:

```
<?php } ?>
```

I recommend you to use some code editor which can show syntax errors while writing code and you need not to waste your as well as our time for such a minor error.